# Cannot get BS5 Toast to Autohide

Tags: bootstrap-5, toast

I've just added some toasts to a website I'm working on. They show absolutely fine, exactly when they should do, but they don't autohide. Doesn't seem to matter how I define the properties.
According to the documentation:
data-bs-autohide has a default value true
data-bs-delay has a default value 5000 (5s)
I striped things right back to basics and added:

```
<div class="toast show" role="assertive" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
        <svg class="rounded me-3" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
            <rect fill="#62c462" width="100%" height="100%" class="me-3 rounded"></rect>
        </svg>
        <strong class="me-auto">TITLE</strong>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
        some body text
    </div>
</div>
```

to the homepage to see what would happen... the toast appears in the top left corner when the page loads (as expected) but does not disappear after 5 seconds.

I added
`data-bs-animation="true" data-bs-autohide="true" data-bs-delay="2000"` to the main toast DIV, expecting that there would be some sort of change in behaviour (some sort of animation on load/hide and that it would auto-hide after 2 seconds), but nothing... just stays there indefinitely just like before I added the additional data-bs-xxx tags.

I saw some other posts talking about this, and they were using Bootstrap 5.0.2 (I'm using 5.2.0) so I tried with the older BS5 distribution, but still exactly the same behaviour.

Any help here would be great - clearly I'm missing something simple/obvious.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...
I got rid of the .show class from the main toast and initialise the toasts with JavaScript instead... then the parameters in the data-bs-xxx are working exactly as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).